# localstorage variable only writes 0 to index.html

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hi when I run this block of code, the result of "clickamt" is 0 and it does not increment:

```
switch (isNaN(incremental) || isNaN(clickamt) || isnull(incremental) || isnull(clickamt) || isnull(curfloat) || isNaN(curfloat)) {
  case true:
    storage.setItem("clickamt", "0");
    clickamt = (parseFloat(storage.getItem("clickamt")).toFixed(1));
    storage.setItem("incremental", "1");
    incremental = (parseInt(storage.getItem("incremental")));
    storage.setItem("curfloat", "0");
    curfloat = (parseFloat(storage.getItem("curfloat")).toFixed(1));
    break;
  case false:
    if (clickamt % 1000 === curfloat) {
      curfloat = (moneylevels()).toFixed(1);
    }
    clickamt = ((clickamt + incremental) + curfloat).toFixed(1);
    incremental++;
    storage.setItem("clickamt", (clickamt));
    storage.setItem("incremental", (incremental).toString());
    storage.setItem("curfloat", (curfloat).toString());
    break;
}
```

The innerHTML of "clickamt" writes 0 and only 0 to "index.html".
I want "clickamt" of type float to increment by using incremental of type int plus curfloat which is of type float.  "curfloat" is incremented by 0.1 per 1000 of "clickamt".
I don't think it's a parsing issue or anything of the sort.  When I recoded it once it would just append the float it would increment by to the end of clickamt.  This made me think there may be a parsing issue somewhere.
Some outputs I've seen are (0, 0.101011,00.010101,1,11,1111111,1111111111,etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check on page load if the value for necessary key exists in localStorage. If the value is missing, then compute and save the new value. You can also have an extra event on which you can override the value of this key, but this will be a user action.

```
 function computeRandomValue() {
      var data = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % data.length;
      return data[index];
    }
    
    function setToLocalStorage(newVal) {
      var lsKey = "_lsTest";
      localStorage.setItem(lsKey, newVal);
    }
    
    function getFromLocalStorage() {
      var lsKey = "_lsTest";
      return localStorage.getItem(lsKey);
    }
    
    function initializePage() {
      var _val = getFromLocalStorage();
    
      if (!(_val && _val.trim().length > 0)) {
        _val = computeAndSaveNewValue();
      }
    
      printValue(_val, "lblResult");
    }
    
    function computeAndSaveNewValue() {
      var newVal = computeRandomValue();
      setToLocalStorage(newVal);
      printValue(newVal);
      return newVal;
    }
    
    function printValue(value) {
      var id = "lblResult";
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }
    
    (function() {
      window.onload = initializePage;
    })()
```